# How do we identify libraries build with NDK is 64-bit supported?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Google saying that **apps using native code / libraries must provide a 64-bit version in addition to the 32-bit version by August 1, 2019**. It's easy to identify the app developed in NDK from it's code. But how do we identify a library which is developed in NDK?

Comment: One way would be to build an APK and see if it contains any `.so` files.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Does your app use native code?](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#does_your_app_include_64-bit_libraries),

> For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in `armeabi-v7a`. The 64-bit equivalent is `arm64-v8a`.
>
> For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and `x86_64` for 64-bit.

So,

> how do we identify a library which is developed in NDK?

Similarly as `.apk`, you can inspect the directory structure of the library, i.e. the `.aar`, has directories like `lib/arm64-v8a/xxx.so` or `lib/x86_64/xxx.so`, if yes, it means this `.aar` is developed as `64-bit`.