# What I have to modifiy for the 64-bit requirement?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, requirements

I know about that:

> Inspect your APK or app bundle for native code.
> You can check for .so files using APK Analyzer.
> Identify whether they are built from your own code or are imported by an SDK or library that you are using.
> If you do not have any .so files in your APK, you are already 64-bit compliant.
>
> Enable 64-bit architectures and rebuild native code (.so files) imported by your own code. See the documentation for more details.
>
> Upgrade any SDKs and libraries to 64-bit compliant versions, if needed. Reach out to the SDK or library owner if one is not available. We’re working with top library owners on their 64-bit compatibility.
>
> Test for issues locally once you’ve rebuilt your app.
> Rollout to your testers using testing tracks for thorough testing.

But I miss anything else? Any recommendations?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#test_your_app_on_64-bit_hardware

Comment: check here also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504068/8034839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no native (NDK) code, that is you only write Java/Dex code, then you don't need to do anything.

If you have native code (or libraries) then you need to supply their 64-bit versions.
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549563/how-to-make-android-apps-which-support-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-architecture)